# Redshift Unload: Add headers only in first partition, excluding the rest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

---

I am unloading redshift table to S3, I want only first partition to contain the `column headers` and other partitions should not include the headers.

However,

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM table') 
TO 's3://bucket/' 
FORMAT CSV 
IAM_ROLE arn:aws:iam::<AccNo>:role/myRedshiftRole' 
HEADER;`
```

adds headers in every partition. Currently I'm executing the query two times(first with header, and then without header), and deleting the unnecessary partitions.

Is there a more efficient way than this?

Comment: Don't think so! How are you using/processing the files after they are created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift produces at least 1 S3 object for every slice in the cluster and then as these files pass a line limit new objects will be created.  So you see there is no "first" file (object or partition), they are all parallels to each other.  (Yes you can go to parallel off but more on that in a moment.) The real question is 'why do you want this?'.  Some other tool or process or person desires it, I expect, but the real question is 'how do I pass the column names to said tool after unloading from Redshift?'.  I'd explore this question more as I expect it will open up the solution space for you.

I've had to solve this exact problem for clients in the past (a requirement from legacy tooling, not really the best approach).  2 approaches:

1. If the data being unloaded is relatively small you can unload with "parallel off".  This will route the unload data back to the leader node which will write a single object in S3 (up to the line limit mentioned earlier).  Then instead of unloading the table in question, unload the UNION of the column names with the data from the table (or query) cast as text.  There are some subtle gotchas that can creep up in this approach, will produce multiple files as data gets larger, and is not very efficient as all data has to be routed through the leader node.  But this approach can be made to work.
2. Produce a separate files with just the header information and define this as "the first" to be read by the downstream process.  This can be made by a separate unload command from Redshift or some other process/tool. The unload of the table (or query) will be unchanged, it expects that there will be multiple files, and Redshift can efficiently produce the objects (in parallel from the compute nodes).  This approach is sounder and safer than #1.

As I said before you really are dealing with a different problem - how to define the DDL of data stored in S3? Or even more broadly how to consistently define the DDL for data that is represented across an entire cloud environment? I've built solutions for these questions too and I can tell you that addressing these will provide more value in the long run than trying to make unload data look like a CSV so tool flows will work.  I do understand the need to get something working now so I hope these suggestions help.

Comment: We use a legacy system, currently importing data from redshift. It requires us to only provide column headers for the first file(000 partition). Currently the data we're using is in CSV, but Parquet files will also be used later. 
That being said, I really liked the second approach, will definitely try it out. Thanks